# R3GUI - How to set the size of an 'area'

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

I've tried:

```
hgroup [label "Note"    64 AFV_Note:    area 100x50]
```

That produces the correct width but the height is still too tall.

I also tried:

```
hgroup [label "Note"    64 AFV_Note:    area options [init-size: 100x50]]
```

That results in an error; probably not an option for 'area'.

Comment: RE: [*"If you thought the documentation for the Visual Interface Dialect was bad, you should try the Draw Dialect."*](http://rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&permalink=Steven%20White20-May-2016/15:15:21-7:00&archiveflag=new) => It might be fair warning to know that r3-gui is not evolving much, and that the most likely GUI future in Redbol will be an based on [Red's GUI system](http://www.red-lang.org/2016/03/060-red-gui-system.html), which has attention being put on it by multiple people.

Comment: Yes, I too was waiting for RED.  But when 6.0 came out with no Android nor mySQL, I thought I would continue to work with R3 and port my code when RED is there.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help at all?

https://github.com/gchiu/RSOChat/blob/master/rsochat.r3#L811

```
chat-area: area "" 600x90 options [min-hint: 750x50 detab: true]
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, it got me trying a bunch of different combos but nothing I've tried makes the height less.  With the 'options' it seems to ignore the first pair of numbers.  I also used init-size of 200x50 and it made the area a bit wider but no less tall.  It seems there is hard coded a limit for the height.  I'll have a look to see if I can figure out why.